# 508 ошибка постоянно кладёт сайт (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress

В последнее время постоянно 508 ошибка из-за одного сайта, хотя особо посещалка не увеличилась.
Перешел на самый мощный тариф на белорусском хостере, но не помогло.

Началось все это пару месяцев назад:

```
[Wed Nov 13 18:07:05.493205 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 1779282] 
   [client 188.246.237.194:0] AH01797: 
   client denied by server configuration: /***/***/***.ru/index.php
[Wed Nov 13 18:07:05.469093 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 1779282]
   [client 188.246.237.194:0] AH01797: 
   client denied by server configuration: /***/***/***.ru/pab-sw.js
```

и таких строк 300 штук за сегодня.

Сайт на WordPress.
Хостер послал... к разработчику.

Как победить проблему?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка 508 возникает, если превышен допустимый лимит обращения к серверу.
Возможно у вас где то есть бесконечный цикл, либо проблемы на стороне вашего хостинга.
Попробуйте установить свою CMS с той же конфигурацией на другой хостинг (к примеру на бесплатный) и просмотреть, что будет, если проблема исчезнет, то виноват ваш хостинг-провайдер, если останется - ищите части кода которые могут вызывать перегрузку сервера.

В любом случаи без самого кода сказать подробнее нельзя (хоть и wordpress, но он возможно модифицирован + изменен шаблон, в котором могут быть части php кода которые и перегружают сервер)

P.S: Немного погуглив удалось узнать, что данная проблема ещё может возникать при некорректной работы Apache-сервера, проблема возникает из-за зависания процессов Apache-сервера из-за неправильной настройки конфигурации самого сервера.

Answer (score 0):

всем спасибо, кто прочитал и Coder, который натолкнул на мысль, что проблема в движке
в итоге, я отключил все плагины (штук 11) и поочередно включал самые необходимые
проблема пропала
но не все плагины еще включены
так что вероятнее всего проблема в каком то плагине